# Compare datetimeoffset with timezone SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have a date `emp_date` which is of type datetime offset.  This date is saved correctly in the database.

I want to retrieve all data having the date `emp_date` less than the actual time, including time zone.

For example, if the `emp_date` is as below:

> 2019-10-25 23:44:09.5798885 +14:00

And I am in a time zone of +2, then the data having the above date should not be retrieved.

Any idea of how to do this?

I want to pass the timezone of the user as parameter.

Comment: Why not use `datetimeoffset` for the parameter as well? Why pass the timezone separately? SQL Server can compare `datetimeoffset` values with different offsets already

Comment: Is the real question `How can I create a datetimeoffset from a datetime and an offset` perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No.  I want to compare two datetime offset for a give timezone

Comment: Then what *is* the question? Because you can just pass a `datetimeoffset`. There's no reason to pass an offset separately. What does your query look like, how do you call it, how do you pass the parameters?

Comment: Actual date of the user and it's timezone

Comment: `I want to compare two datetime offset for a give timezone` what does that mean? The values can be compared directly. There's no need to convert them to the same offset. Post an example that demonstrates the problem - source data, query, expected results

Answer (score 0):

https://dzone.com/articles/dates-and-times-in-sql-server-at-time-zone
pass the needed time zone as parameter, then we can convert to the needed time zone.

```html
DECLARE @TimeZone varchar(50)
SET @TimeZone = 'Central European Standard Time'
SELECT getdate() AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone AS date
```

```html
SELECT getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' AS date
```